# Hide all kernel boot messages/logging when disabling splash screen Lubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, lubuntu

In Lubuntu 13.10 I was able to redirect the kernel messages/logging to another `tty` by adding the following to the Grub file in order to hide all kernel boot messages when disabling the splash screen and it booted very quickly:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"
```

However when I add the same line to Grub in Lubuntu 14.04.1 I still get all of the boot/logging messages, which actually is taking much longer to boot than having the splash screen present.

Is there a way to hide all the boot messages applicable to Lubuntu 14.04.1, as it appears redirecting the kernel messages to another `tty` isn't working.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

**Edit (regarding marus' answer)**: Yes, after I added the new parameter and deleted "splash" I did run `sudo update-grub` and the new parameter was present after updating and also after re-booting and splash was not present.

Yes I did delete "splash" and kept "quiet".

I still receive a whole screen worth of boot/logging messages. I also tried `console=tty6` and `console=tty9` and neither worked. I still receive boot messages.

The only way to not receive boot messages is to re-add "splash".

Comment: Is this problem solved? Even I'm working on it. And I changed the configuration by removing splash and keeping quiet and I got a kernel panic :-|

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up trying to resolve the situation. There probably is a solution I just haven't found one as of yet. So I have kept the spash screen as is.

Comment: I am having problem while switching to `X` after boot animation completes. I am getting some boot logs before switching to `X`. It is like....Boot animation completes and I ll get some boot logs and then it will switch to `X` :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to see the messages in the TTY, then you can set the `quiet` parameter instead. By default, you have `quiet splash`, just delete the `splash`.

Comment: Yes I did keep the "quiet" parameter. I still receive a whole screen of boot messages. The only way to not get the messages is to re-add the "splash" parameter.